# footsmisc perpage-option applied to other but standard footnote

Tags: footnotes, footmisc, bigfoot

I have two sets of footnotes defined in the document (Basically I am trying to get around a "counter too large" error on the second set.):

```
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % standard, loads of them = \footnote{}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[alph] % about 75 = \footnoteD{}

%\usepackage{perpage}
%   \MakePerPage{footnoteD}
\usepackage[multiple,perpage]{footmisc}
```

(no point in providing a working example with 27+ footnotes)

As is it works resetting \footnote{} as desired. Instead I'd like to have \footnoteD{} reset on every page.

The following alternatives do not work (compiling with XeTeX):

- Using perpage (see above) throws an error: Command \c@abspage already defined. \newcounter{abspage}
- Setting \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[Roman] would be an alternative, but results in a rather odd display of the Roman footnote numbers (see image below), in that only some characters are above baseline. (Using a different font is not feasible due to large number of "odd" glyps required)

If necessary, I could live with reseting \footnote{} every page using alaph-Footnote marks and arabic numerals for \footnoteD{} but don't know how to define that.

[image: Roman XXX not as footnote]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `alphalph` for this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}  
\usepackage{bigfoot}  
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} % standard, loads of them = \footnote{}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[alph] 
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteD}{%   
  \alphalph{\value{footnoteD}}}    

\begin{document} 
Regular footnote.\footnote{Regular}   
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}  
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}   
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}   
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}   
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}   
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}  
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}   
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}    
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}     
words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf} words.\footnoteD{adf}  
\end{document}
```